# Calico: How felix update the iptables rules and ip routes at host?

Tags: networking, iptables, calico

As known, the calico/node could run inside a contianer, including the fleix. I do not understand how it r/w the iptables rules and routes at the host, since both in different network namespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I forget the container uses host network (--net=host), so it could access the iptables and ip routes on host.